# Vue FullCalendar how to set options dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I need dynamically change some options in Vue FullCalendar, but calendar didn't apply it.

Please look my example https://codesandbox.io/s/3q2j3r7pjq

Button in bottom set maxTime option from 20:00 to 18:00

How i can refresh calendar view?

Answer (score 3):

I found it =)

```js
this.$refs.calendar.fireMethod('option', optionName, optionValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define reference for the calendar component and call setOption on its api

```
<full-calendar :config="config" :events="events" ref="fullCalendar" />
...
this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi().setOption('maxTime', '18:00:00');
```